# Google Picker, get OAuth token

Tags: oauth, picker, google-picker

I am using Google Picker inside of my project. Now, it has to use the OAuth token or you get the message ("Invalid credentials (missing or invalid oAuth token)").

I want to get that token from my user. I don't know how to do it.

I know it has to use OAuth 3-legged to get permissions of my client.

Can you help me, please?

Diego.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I have manage my problem using OAuth 2.0 and this [library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/). Ask me if you have any problem.

Comment: Instead of saying "Ask me", please consider posting your code so that it will help others